# AndroidX JetPack NavigationUI - Overriding Action on Non-Navigation Item In Drawer

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation-drawer, android-jetpack, androidx

I just started using Android NavigationUI to implement Fragment Navigation through a drawer menu. While it does feel a bit like magic, I have one main issue with it. That is, I have a `logout` item in the menu that should not Navigate to any Fragment, but rather to an "action". While I found similar questions here such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52699935/android-jetpack-navigation-custom-action-with-drawer-item) one, I haven't found a clear answer to my question yet. The following is the function I'm currently using to setup the navigation:

```
private fun setupNav() {
    val binding: ActivityMainMenuBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,
            R.layout.activity_main_menu)
    drawerLayout = binding.drawerLayout
    navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.content_frame)
    appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(navController.graph, drawerLayout)

    // Set up ActionBar
    setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar)
    setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
    binding.navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
}
```

If you have any suggestions on how I could approach this, it would be truly appreciated if you could share them.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to add below mentioned code

```
    nav_view.menu.findItem(R.id.nav_logout).setOnMenuItemClickListener {
            Log.e("=>"," You clicked on logout !!! ")
            true
        }
```

and Here is my full code

```
    class NavigationDrawerActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var appBarConfig: AppBarConfiguration

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation_drawer)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        val navController: NavController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)

        appBarConfig = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(
                R.id.nav_home,
                R.id.nav_gallery,
                R.id.nav_slideshow,
                R.id.nav_tools,
                R.id.nav_share,
                R.id.nav_send
            )
            , drawer_layout
        )

        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfig)
        nav_view.setupWithNavController(navController)

        //For log out button related stuff
        nav_view.menu.findItem(R.id.nav_logout).setOnMenuItemClickListener {
            Log.e("=>"," You clicked on logout !!! ")
            true
        }
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        return findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment).navigateUp(appBarConfig)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }
}
```

You can also `check out` my project from `Git Hub` by this [this link](https://github.com/sakib143/NavigationUI-Demo)